# What's the "Combo" OS X Update?

Tags: macos, software-update

What's the difference between the **OS X Mountain Lion Update v10.8.5** and the **OS X Mountain Lion Update v10.8.5 (Combo)** packages?

I'm running OS X 10.8.4

Comment: Maybe not related, but if you use Skype be aware that the 10.8.5 does not support Video calling (for now).

Answer (score 4):

**Combo Update** allows you to update from whichever Mountain Lion version you’re using. It means you can update from v10.8.1 to v10.8.5 immediately.

While **OS X Mountain Lion Update v10.8.5** means you can only update from the previous version, which is only **OS X 10.8.4**.